# How to display French character encoding in RSS feed with python using feedgen

Tags: python, flask, rss

I am using [Feedgen](https://feedgen.kiesow.be/api.feed.html) to generate a RSS feed but how can I set the encoding to show French character.

app.py

```
# Flask package
# pip install flask
from flask import make_response
from flask import Flask, Response

# Other Python external packages
# pip install feedgen
from feedgen.feed import FeedGenerator

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

def get_feed_object():
    fg = FeedGenerator()
    fg.title("STO Bug")
    fg.description(
        "STO question"
    )
    fg.link(href="https://sto.com")
    return fg

@app.route("/", methods=("GET",))
def rss():

    fg = get_feed_object()

    downloads = [
        {
            'Survey': "Enquête sociale générale, cycle 29",
        },
        {
            'Survey': 'Enquête sociale générale, cycle 30',
        }
    ]

    for survey in downloads[:20]:
        fe = fg.add_entry()
        fe.title(
            survey["Survey"]
        )

    response = make_response(fg.rss_str(encoding='UTF-8'))
    response.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/rss+xml")

    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I need to set the encoding in the response.header

```
response.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8")
```